# Unable to create so file for arm64-v8a with Superpowered library

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, superpowered

I integrated the Superpowered Library in my application. I added all the .a files in the jni folder.All files are successfully compiled and generates the so file except arm64-v8a architecture. I used the "libSuperpoweredAndroidARM64.a" file. Can you please help me to generate the so file for this architecture. It shows following error

```
In function `SuperpoweredCompressor::process(float*, float*, unsigned int)':
    /Volumes/iMect/iphone/SuperpoweredSource/FX/SuperpoweredCompressor.cpp:254: undefined reference to `SuperpoweredCompressorProcess'
    /Volumes/iMect/iphone/SuperpoweredSource/FX/SuperpoweredCompressor.cpp:254: undefined reference to `SuperpoweredCompressorProcess'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the current version of Superpowered, which is based on CMake. Google has changed the rules of the Android native environment from the experimental plugin to CMake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me check the updated android native environment.